# Problems using Arduino to XBee and Arduino to MATLAB

Tags: matlab, arduino, xbee

I have coordinate values (longitude and latitude), and I am sending these coordinates form Arduino 1 to Arduino 2 using an [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) module.

I have received these coordinates at Arduino 2 correctly, but I also want to display these coordinates (from Arduino 2 to) on MATLAB (using MATLAB serial communication).

The code at the Arduino 2 is same for receiving the coordinates from Arduino 1 (via XBee) as well as for sending these coordinates on MATLAB (via serial communication).

The command for sending data serially from Arduino 2 to MATLAB is `Serial.print(data)` or `Serial.write(data)`, but the problem is that the same command is used for sending the data from arduino-2 to arduino-1.

Therefore, I am unable to get the data on MATLAB.

How do I get the Arduino 2 data on MATLAB serially?

Comment: Maybe you can use an additional `SoftwareSerial` instance in the arduino-2 to write the incoming data from arduino-1 to a serial communication for MATLAB?

Comment: Thanks! for your kind response. I need more detail, please help me.